# customize ticks label when sharex is on in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two stacked subplots which share the x axis, for both subplots visibility of ticks is set to false because I don't want to see tick labels. after having plotted both subplots, I would like to put some extra  ticks on x-asis, only for second subplot, but they don't have to became the main ticks.
I mean, doing this:

```
        #xticks = list of x points
        #xlabs = list of labels
        #secondplot.set_xticks(xticks) 
        #secondplot.set_xticklabels(xlabs)
```

will change the first sublplot grid according to these new ticks as if they became the new major ticks. is there a way to label just some x-axis point in second subplot without affecting the whole plots area? thank you

Answer (score 2):

I know im late to the party but I faced a similar problem and want to share my solution, in case anyone else needs help.

You can use [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html) to control the style of both major and minor ticks of the axes. Setting the tick lengths of the first subplot to 0 should do the trick:

```py
ax.tick_params(axis="x", which="both", length=0.)
```

*axis* ("x", "y" or "both") selects the axes, on which the setting has an effect, *which* ("major", "minor" or "both") chooses the tick type.
Of course you can then also set major and minor ticks with `ax.set_xticks(ticks, minor=False)`. A full example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex="col")
axarr[0].plot(range(11))
axarr[1].plot(range(11)[::-1])

axarr[0].tick_params(axis="x", which="both", length=0.)
axarr[1].set_xticks(range(0, 11, 3))
axarr[1].set_xticks(range(0, 11), minor=True)

plt.show()
```

which yields: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc7y0.png

Answer (score 1):

This works for removing the tick labels from a single axis when using `sharex`, but I don't see a solution to also remove the ticks..

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

pl.figure()
ax1=pl.subplot(211)
ax1.plot([0,10],[0,10])

ax2=pl.subplot(212, sharex=ax1)
ax2.plot([0,10],[10,0])

pl.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
```

[image]